# Не ставятся некоторые пакеты в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Хотел поставить некоторые пакеты

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty
```

И вот такое выбивает:

> Reading package lists... Done
>       Building dependency tree
>       Reading state information... Done
>       E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-trusty
>       E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-lts-trusty
>       E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Не устанавливает только эти пакеты или вообще никакие? Скорее всего, не добавлены нужные репозитории. А если добавлены, то для обновления нужно выполнить apt-get update.

Comment: @maestro только эти не ставятся. перед этим делал `apt-get update`. скорее всего это не добавлен нужный репозиторий. может знаете какой нужен?

Comment: Отредактируйте sources.list, как указано здесь: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/precise/amd64/linux-generic-lts-trusty/download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как указано в описании, например, пакета [linux-generic-lts-trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/precise/amd64/linux-generic-lts-trusty/download), вам надо добавить примерно такую строку:

```
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu precise-security main
```

в файл `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

после чего обновите списки пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

и повторите попытку установки.

---

для пакета [xserver-xorg-lts-trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/xserver-xorg-lts-trusty/download) надо добавить примерно такую строку:

```
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu trusty-updates main
```

Comment: Спасибо. так уже сделал. некоторые пакеты нашло. но вот теперь такое выбивает `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-lts-trusty`

Comment: @SkiesX, дополнил ответ.